# How can I stop Eclipse from asking to install Subversive Connectors

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I'm using Eclipse Helios v3.6 and every time I start up I get the following dialog.  Yet I do not use subversion.  Does anyone know how to make this stop?

[image: Subversive Connector Discovery]

Comment: Interesting - that's the Mylyn connector discovery UI.  You see it whenever you launch the IDE?

Comment: Yup - everytime I restart the app I see this dialog.  I select cancel since I'm not running subversion.

Comment: @Ladlestein The Mylyn connector discovery UI has been contributed to the platform, e.g. the Marketplace UI is based on the same. A similar discovery UI is used for Subversive connector selection as well.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. To fix it I went into my Eclipse plug-ins directory and searched for anything with "svn", "subversion", or "subclipse" in the filename. I removed the following JAR's and relaunched Eclipse. So far so good.

```
01/19/2011  09:37 AM             8,262 com.smartbear.collaborator.subclipse_6.0.6016.jar
01/19/2011  09:37 AM            19,556 com.smartbear.collaborator.subversive_6.0.6016.jar
01/19/2011  09:37 AM            10,539 com.smartbear.collaborator.ui.subclipse_6.0.6016.jar
01/19/2011  09:37 AM            11,093 com.smartbear.collaborator.ui.subversive_6.0.6016.jar
05/04/2011  11:03 AM           943,141 org.eclipse.team.svn.core_0.7.9.I20110207-1700.jar
05/04/2011  11:04 AM         2,490,582 org.eclipse.team.svn.ui_0.7.9.I20110207-1700.jar
05/04/2011  11:44 AM            82,086 org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter_1.6.12.jar
05/04/2011  11:44 AM           297,927 org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core_1.6.17.jar
05/04/2011  11:44 AM         1,928,100 org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui_1.6.17.jar
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks! I had uninstalled Subversive, but the prompt kept on bugging me. Not anymore :)

Comment: I have downvoted this answer, because it is really a bad idea to manually mess around with the plugins directory. You can simply uninstall stuff using Help/About, and then selecting installation details. Yes, I know, it is hidden, but that is a better functionality.

Comment: As suggested by Zoltán Ujhelyi, the correct way is to uninstall using "Eclipse -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details"

Comment: Agreed with Zoltán

Answer (score 5):

Either install one provider - than in would not appear again - or uninstall the Subversive plug-in (Help/About/Installation details; and look for the Subversive elements to uninstall).

Answer (score 4):

I started getting the same problem after I installed the Papyrus plugin. I had to remove a few JAR files in my Eclipse plugin directory containing "svn" in the name. I first tried to see if I could uninstall from Eclipse's 'Help' menu, as Zoltan explained, but there was no option to independently remove the SVN plugin without removing Papyrus entirely. But removing the JAR files seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I can share that experience. I was being asked for Subversive connectors although I had not installed Subversive. No way to uninstall anything obvious. Performing `rm *svn*` in the plugins directory helped greatly.

Comment: I mirror this experience. I uninstalled only Papyrus and it fixed it. (What a bloated plugin that is)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the startup interface for installing the connector does not work
I installed one of the available connectors using Help->Install new software...
and then using this update site

http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/juno-site/

taken from http://www.polarion.com

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here: does any of the projects in your workspace have the SVN metadata `.svn` by chance? I'd guess that could be the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstall all "subversive" plugins in the `"Install New Software->already installed"` and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I went the other route and just installed the whole package under Subversive. This allowed me to complete the installation and the splash screen no longer pops up. Figured Subversive would be something that is handy to have available